# Socket Exception: Peer crashing vs. socket is closed (locally or remotely)

Tags: java, networking

> Socket Exception: Peer crashing vs. socket is closed (locally or remotely).

I want my code to branch on the conditions:

- The remote endpoint called`close()`on the remote Socket.
- The remote endpoint chrashed abnormaly.
- My own code called`close()`on the local Socket.

Sometimes, I call `close()` on my own Socket object to make it resume from a call to `readObject()` (associated stream). This causes a `SocketException`.

What about the other two cases; Do they throw some other `Exception` type that my code can branch upon?

Comment: For a graceful close I send a poison pill message and have the other end close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

At least for your intended closes: Just send a packet, string or byte (whatever you want) that tells the remote connection that the socket is going to be closed. Then the remote handler can close the socket, too.

If one of the sockets is closed and the remote partner tries to read from it further, it will get an Exception (I don't remember the exact exception, but it is one of them you need to catch anyways), that you can catch and shut down the socket on the remote side, too.